# Django. Reuse included template with different variable

Tags: django, django-templates

I am using a {% include %} in one of my templates, I would like to use the same Html included but replacing the name of the variable with a different one:

The {% include %} (included html):

```
{% if post.1 %}
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <p class = "vote-id hidden">{{post.0.id}}</p>
        <button type="button" class = "btn btn-default vote-up"> 
            <span class="fa fa-chevron-up"></span>
        </button>
...
{% endif %}
```

The variable is usually called "post", but in one template I can't call it "post", I need to include the same html but with a different variable, is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `include` [template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#include) takes an optional `with` assignment, which you can use to rename your variable:

```
{% include 'your-template.html' with post=obj %}
```